# Why does my unit test return 'cannot read property 'simulate' of undefined' in this React test?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have an app which renders several cards by mapping an array object. Each card has a button, on click it increases the item cost. Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-goodall-8no6x

Here is the code:

Home.js:

```js
const cards = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "car",
    price: 10
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "bike",
    price: 20
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "plane",
    price: 30
  }
];

const Home = () => {
  const [totalPrice, setTotalPrice] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = (id, qty) => {
    let newState = [...totalPrice];
    if (newState.find((item) => item.id === id) !== undefined) {
      newState.find((item) => item.id === id).qty += qty;
    } else {
      newState.push({ id: id, qty: qty });
    }
    setTotalPrice(newState);
  };

  return cards.map((d) => {
    const stateItem = totalPrice.find((item) => item.id === d.id); 
    const qty = stateItem ? stateItem.qty : 0; 
    return (
      <Card
        key={d.id}
        id={d.id}
        testid={d.id}
        title={d.title}
        price={d.price}
        totalPrice={d.price * qty}
        handleClick={handleClick}
      />
    );
  });
};

export default Home;
```

Card.js

```js
import React from "react";

const Card = ({ id, testid, title, price, totalPrice, handleClick }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div key={id} data-testid={testid}>
        <p>
          {id}. {title}
        </p>
        <p>Price: {price}</p>
        <p className="total-price">{totalPrice}</p>
        <button className="add" onClick={() => handleClick(id, 1)}>
          Add 1
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

Now I want to test `Home.js` functionality in a black box. My idea is simple: find all buttons with 'add' class, find the first element and simulate clicking it, test if the text of that card is 10.

Here is the `Home.test.js`:

```js
import React from "react";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import { shallow, configure } from "enzyme";
import Home from "./Home";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe("Test functions", () => {
  it("should display the correct button to be tested", () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<Home />);
    expect(getByTestId("1")).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it("should display the correct cost when add button is clicked", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Home />);
    const buttons = wrapper.find(".add");
    buttons[0].simulate("click");
    expect(wrapper.find(".total-price")[0].text()).toBe("10");
  });
});
```

It gives me `TypeError: Cannot read property 'simulate' of undefined`, I don't understand why no button was found, how can I find the correct node and test on it?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to do something, like `wrapper.find('.add').at(0).simulate('click')`? `.find()` is supposed to return a wrapper. not an array

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov I tried `wrapper.find('.add').at(0).simulate('click');`, gave me error: `Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, in shallow rendering only Card component (just the wrapper without leaf nodes) will be rendered. So if you need all lead nodes be rendered you need to use `mount` instead.

Morever you could console log the result of your `find(".add")` something like-

```js
console.log(buttons.debug())
```

> I'd recommend logging it before you change the shallow to mount. Just to get an idea what's being rendered.

The import will be

```js
import { mount, shallow, configure } from "enzyme";
```

And the test will be

```js
it("should display the correct cost when add button is clicked", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Home />); // render everything
    console.log(wrapper.debug()); // check what's being rendered
    const buttons = wrapper.find(".add");
    console.log(buttons.debug()); // log found nodes
    buttons.at(0).simulate("click"); // use at selector
    expect(wrapper.find(".total-price").at(0).text()).toBe("10");
  });
```

Comment: Good point, how can I check the console log? Jest just gave me pass or fail and the explanation in terminal, I don't know where to see the rendered component in browser

Comment: Can you show me how to write the test by updating your answer?

Comment: I tried it and could see `console.log(buttons.debug());` logs 3 buttons, but `buttons[0].simulate("click")` gives me error: `Cannot read property 'simulate' of undefined`

Comment: You need at selector to get 0th element. Updated code